# Como acessar um header específico de um http response?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, token, jwt

Tenho uma API Rest em Java, que faz uso de JWT para autenticar usuários e gerar tokens para acesso de seus recursos. Possuo uma aplicação em AngularJS, que deverá consumir estes recursos, mas preciso primeiro requisitar um token na API. Gostaria de saber como posso acessar o token que está no header da resposta da requisição POST. Pelo Angular não estou conseguindo acesso a isto, porém, no navegador consigo visualizar o token na resposta da requisição.

[image: Exemplo da resposta da requisição, com o token no header]

Answer (score 3):

```
$http.post('/login', user).then(function(response) {
    var authorization = response.headers('Authorization');
});
```

Com a função headers() pode acessar qualquer um dos atributos do cabeçalho.